# Animating 3d model with .fbx format in xna 4.0

Tags: 3d, xna, xna-4.0, fbx

Anybody please help me to animate the 3d model of .fbx format in xna 4.0. if any tutorial or sample applications are  there pl show me the way. i'm new to xna and 3d models intact i'm new to this whole gaming concept. i need to build one arm wrestling game in 2 weeks so pl help me out. if any other way to build the game apart from xna pl refer those too. i need samples and tutorials since i have not enough time to learn and build from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

*The fastest way to build 3D games is in my experience still Unity3D. Which will allow you to write your games in C#, which you probably know already as you are trying to program a game with XNA 4.0. On top of that it has a solid editor and great UI. It's easy to learn and there are enough free tutorials you can find about it. You can find the official website [unity3d.com](http://unity3d.com/). (it's free to use)*

To talk about your problem. You can play .FBX format's, but in my experience with XNA 4.0, it's still better to use the *.x format (text, not binary). For this format are several samples, that can be found online.

- [This](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model) is an official sample, where you can see how to load the skinned model as an asset, process the information and how to control it. (if you look around you can find also other samples, similar to this one.)
- [www.enchantedage.com/xna-animation](http://www.enchantedage.com/xna-animation) is a library, free to use, that makes your life easier for animations. There are similar libraries that can be found as well if you search hard enough.
- For a project at university I used [this library](http://communistgames.blogspot.be/2010/12/animation-library-for-xna-40.html), which worked great for me.

If you want to have it even easier, you can even choose to use a complete engine, build on top of XNA. [Engine Nine](http://nine.codeplex.com/) is a great example of this, and again it's free to use.

It's up to you what you want to use. As an additional note. If you're using 3DS Max, be sure to work with the 2012 edition. You can download the plugin [here](http://www.andytather.co.uk/panda/directxmax_downloads.aspx), I worked with it for the same project and it worked as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use XNA, the Microsoft sample for skeletal animation is here:
[Microsoft Skinned Model Sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model)

But a much better sample can be found here:
[Better Skinned Sample](http://metlab.cse.msu.edu/betterskinned.html)